Learning about reflecting graphs across axes, not understanding reflection across y-axis.
So I have been learning about translations of functions and graphs, and so far I have learned:

Vertical/Horizontal shift of a function
Vertical/Horizontal stretch/compression of a function

And now I have learned reflection of functions across x-axis / y-axis.
Understanding reflection across x-axis wasn't too difficult, but y-axis was the problem for me.
As you know, the reflection of a function f across y-axis would be (y = f(x), y= f(-x))
But suppose a function, y = \sqrt{x + 1}. In order to reflect this across y-axis (technically not y-axis, but reflect it vertically) we would write as y = \sqrt{-((x+1))}. So my questions are:

Why do we negate or put the negative sign on all of the expression instead of just changing x into -x?
In case of translated functions like the one above, it is not technically reflecting across y-axis. Do we say that we reflect it vertically in this case? My instructor also said that we are reflecting across the line of equation that makes the equation 0, basically x+1 = 0, x= -1. So we are reflecting the graph across the line x = -1. Why is this true?
For horizontal reflection, we just have to simply put the negate sign over the whole function. For example, f(x) = (x+2)^2 - 5, reflecting it over x-axis would be -(x+2)^2 + 5, so why does this thing occur for vertical reflections?


This is my first post guys, if the post isn't clear I'll try and clarify it more in the comments. Also how do you guys format the text so the sqrt sign is used, instead of the raw text?? (I googled it and tried to replicate it but failed horribly, lol)

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

$\sqrt{x+1}$ is probably what you want. You have to put the $....$ around it, so that the stack exchange renderer knows to interpret the stuff between as LaTeX.

You can see how to write expressions by editing other peoples answers.
A function can include many operations on a variable.  When you plot you take the final result.  You also define the range and domain of the variables involved. It can get quite involved.  When you take the mirror of a function you map across a line.  For each point in the domain of the function you take the closest point to the line, and then go again the same distance away from the line.  Taking across the x-axis you go from,  for each point pair (x, f(x)) to  (x, -f(x)),  that is y = -f(x).
Instead of functions, I suggest you try taking the mirror image of individual points first.  If you take the point (3,7) what is the mirror image across the y axis?  The closest point on axis is (0,7),  you go twice as far and you get to (-3,7).  For the function you go from (x,f(x))  to  (-x,f(x)).  Try this for many points with different lines to go across to practice reflections. You can put in -x for x and get (x,f(-x)). But that can be harder than it looks. You have to consider do you have a -x for each x in your range.  For me,  looking at individual values, such as the extreme value (or approaching extreme value) of a range really helps. Look at what input values do to the corresponding points.
This is maybe more confusing are as you are changing the x you put in for the function.  In general you really do not want to think about functions as taking the x as the value you gave.  You need to be open to other "parametric" forms.  For example,  you can have a parameter $\theta$ that goes from zero to 2 $\pi$ and have it map to a set of points
(cos($\theta$),sin($\theta$))
to get a circle. You could add a radius by multiplying both the cos and sin by $r$ and let  $r$ have one value such as 2.

When trying to understand reflection across the $x$ axis versus reflection across the $y$-axis, I like to to express the function in the format $y=f(x)$, and then:

To reflect across the $y$-axis, replace $x$ by $-x$ everywhere you see it:
$$y=f(-x)
$$
Keep in mind: the whole expression $f(x)$ might have more than one occurrence of $x$ in it. You have to separately replace each occurrence of $x$ with $-x$. Then, perhaps, simplify.
To reflect across the $x$-axis, replace $y$ by $-y$, everywhere you see it (which is in just one place, namely all alone on the left hand side of the equation):
$$-y = f(x)
$$
But then we like to clean up the equation of the new function, so that $y$ is all alone on the left hand side. So we do one more step of solving for $y$ by negating both sides of the equation:
$$y = -f(x)
$$
Then, perhaps, simplify further.

Let's do this with your example in 1:
$$y = \sqrt{x+1}
$$
First, to reflect $y = \sqrt{x+1}$ across the $x$-axis, replace $y$ with $-y$:
$$-y = \sqrt{x+1}
$$
$$y = -\sqrt{x+1}
$$
Second, to reflect $y = \sqrt{x+1}$ across the $y$-axis, replace $x$ with $-x$:
$$y = \sqrt{-x+1}
$$
What you wrote in item 1, namely $\sqrt{-(x+1)}$, is not correct.

For your example in 3, $y=(x+2)^2-5$, to reflect across the $x$ axis we have
$$-y = (x+2)^2 - 5
$$
and then clean up to get
$$y = -\left( (x+2)^2 - 4 \right)
$$
You simplify the right hand side further, if you like.
And to reflect across the $y$-axis we have
$$y = ((-x)+2)^2 - 5
$$
Again, what you wrote in item 3 is not correct.

One more example to emphasize the point about having more than one occurrence of $x$ in the function expression $f(x)$:
$$y = x^3 + x + 1
$$
To reflect across the $y$ axis, replace $x$ by $-x$ everywhere you see it, so
$$y = (-x)^3 + (-x) + 1
$$
Then simplify:
$$y = -x^3 -x + 1
$$
To reflect across the $x$-axis, replace $y$ by $-y$:
$$-y = x^3 + x + 1
$$
Then simplify by negating both sides:
$$y = -x^3 - x - 1
$$

Yes, you're right. I think I asked the question in a wrong way, because in order to reflect a function in the y-axis you have to replace x by -x everywhere.
The question I wanted to ask is, if we want to reflect a function right-left (or left-right), we need to put the negative sign over the whole equation of the function. Like, in the example $$y = \sqrt{x+1}
$$
If we replace it with
$$y = \sqrt{-(x+1)}
$$
we will get the original function
$$y = \sqrt{x+1}
$$
reflected across the line x = -1.
I'm not sure why this is different from just reflecting across the y-axis.

That's exactly what my answer explains. Namely: you put the minus sign in front of the $x$'s for reflecting across the $y$-axis; and you put the minus sign in front of the $y$'s for reflecting across the $x$-axis. All other effects follow from those two rules, applying algebra. The reason why the method you are asking about is not just reflecting across the $y$-axis is two fold: it is not the same as the correct method, namely putting the minus sign in front of the $x$'s; and, as you can amply demonstrate, it gives the wrong answer on various examples.
